# ActiveMQ throws OOME when creating a large number of topics

Tags: messaging, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.2 and my application requires a large number of topics, somewhere in the neighbourhood of 500,000.  When I run my application, after creating only about 1000 topics, ActiveMQ throws an OutOfMemoryException.

Is it unreasonable to expect ActiveMQ to support this number of topics?

Is there an optimal configuration for this usage?

This thread details the issue: http://www.nabble.com/java.lang.OutOfMemoryError%3A-unable-to-create-new-native-thread-on-AMQ-5.0-td17005441.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is an interesting thread but it did not result in a jira issue so I wonder if *not* using the dedicated task runner is the solution here. 
Using a thread pool instead of a dedicated task runner should decouple the creation of destinations from the creation of threads.
If this is not the case, then please [open a jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/activemq/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) and assign it to me.

There is some more general info @ http://activemq.apache.org/javalangoutofmemory.html

Comment: Turing off the dedicated task runner solves the OutOfMemoryException problem.  However, the system grinds to halt once I hit about 50,000 topics. I'm still curious what the practical limit of topics is.  I realize this depends largely on hardware, but would be nice to know if there are benchmarks.